# Haskell Cabal regenerate documentation for all installed packages

Tags: haskell, documentation, cabal

How can I generate and install documentation for all locally installed cabal packages? I turned on the documentation flag in ~/.cabal/config which means that all newly installed packages will have documentation also generated. But how to generate documentation for all already installed packages?

Is there a way to automatically `cabal install --reinstall` all already installed packages? And more importantly, is that a good idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a recent-ish version of `cabal-install` (>= 0.10, I think), you can try doing

```bsh
$ cabal install --reinstall --upgrade-dependencies world
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work in my case:

```
$ cabal install --dry-run --reinstall world
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure Agda-2.2.10. It requires haskell-src-exts >=1.9.6 &&
<1.10
For the dependency on haskell-src-exts >=1.9.6 && <1.10 there are these
packages: haskell-src-exts-1.9.6. However none of them are available.
haskell-src-exts-1.9.6 was excluded because haskell-src-exts-1.11.1 was
selected instead
haskell-src-exts-1.9.6 was excluded because hlint-1.8.12 requires
haskell-src-exts ==1.11.*
```

If you bump into an error like this, you can try manually editing the `~/.cabal/world` file.

Comment: That worked! Not perfectly.. But almost. It did not get all the dependencies of all the packages and the generated docs do not have a proper index or links to sources but it's a great improvement over not having any local docs at all. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, the world file lists only manually installed packages, so the automatically installed dependencies are not reinstalled (unless there's a new version on Hackage).

Comment: @monadic Thanks, fixed. I was thinking about Cabal version.

Answer (score 3):

Please note that `cabal install --only-dep --reinstall` [does not work](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/1829).

If you are using a sandbox, you can do

```
cabal sandbox delete
cabal sandbox init
cabal install -j --only-dep --enable-documentation
```

The `-j` option allows it to build in parallel.

Answer (score -2):

You could try something like this in bash.

```
for pkg in `ghc-pkg list --simple`
do
cabal install $pkg --reinstall
done
```

But I really don't know, whether it's a good idea.

Comment: it will try to reinstall `ghc`, `base`, etc. Don't try it ;)

Comment: You can use `ghc-pkg --simple --user` to list only user-installed packages.