# Haddock can't find the documentation for installed packages

Tags: haskell, cabal, haddock

I'm trying to make the documentation for my package. When I run the `cabal haddock --executable` it gives the following output:

```
Running Haddock for Geometroid-0.1...
Warning: The documentation for the following packages are not installed. No
links will be generated to these packages: array-0.4.0.0, base-4.5.0.0,
rts-1.0, deepseq-1.3.0.0, ghc-prim-0.2.0.0, integer-gmp-0.4.0.0,
old-locale-1.0.0.4, random-1.0.1.1, time-1.4
Preprocessing test suite 'test-fighter' for Geometroid-0.1...
Preprocessing executable 'fighter' for Geometroid-0.1...
Haddock coverage:
  20% (  1 /  5) in 'Fighter'
Warning: Fighter: could not find link destinations for:
    GHC.Types.Int GHC.Show.Show System.Random.Random GHC.Types.Double GHC.Classes.Eq GHC.Classes.Ord
Documentation created: dist/doc/html/Geometroid/fighter/index.html
```

And in the generated documentation there are indeed no links to built-in types.

I tried generating all the documentation for installed packages according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6568323/113134), but it didn't change anything.

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 with `haskell-platform` installed via `apt-get`.

How can I generate the complete documentation with all the proper links?

Comment: A bit more background please: What kind of system? How did you install GHC? Platform installer or distribution package? If on Debian or Ubuntu, try installing `ghc-doc`.

Comment: @JoachimBreitner Please see update in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the Haskell packages provided by your distribution (which seems to be the case), then the documentation comes in separate packages. In your case, `apt-get install haskell-platform-doc` or just `apt-get install ghc-doc` should help.

Comment: It helped indeed: now there are all the links and the only thing which annoys me is the warning about `rts` package: `Warning: The documentation for the following packages are not installed. No
links will be generated to these packages: rts-1.0`. I couldn't even find what the package is for.

Comment: I have that too and I’ve been ignoring it for long. You can probably do the same.